# Why sharepoint adds automaticaly one hour

Tags: date-time, list-item

I have Date and time field, where I set default date and time, f.e. 1.1.2018 10:00 AM. When I add item due to new item button, date and time is set right and I can save it. But when I use quick edit mode, time is one hour ahead (11:00 AM). Why?

Comment: using admin account, go to Site Settings > Regional settings and change them as per your time zone. After that check if the behaviour persists.

Comment: Thanks, but my Regional settings is right, just +1 hour and when I change it to UTC, time in the field is right but time of item change is one hour in past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I resolved it by setting default value with caltulated value as it is in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f6de7e57-ccf0-437e-aee7-533a63f07d4d/date-and-time-field-calculated-default-value-with-time?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy), so =today+"10:00 AM"